# Column Chart is not Printing when all values are negative

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart that is feeded with positive and negative values, and I thought that it was working perfectly, but suddenly I realize that the columns are not printed when all values are negative....Is there anything I am doing bad??

Here is my code:

```
new Highcharts.chart('av2', {
            chart: {
                type: 'column',
                height: 500,                   
            },
            series: [{
            name: 'Direct Purchase',
            data: [ { y: -1.82, name: 'DK' }, { y: -19.8, name: 'DL' }]
        }]
  });
```

**Mixed Values**: https://jsfiddle.net/zowcqz09/6/

**All Negative Values**: https://jsfiddle.net/zowcqz09/5/

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Definitely a bug in v6. Even the [official demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-negative/) doesn't render anything if you change it to all negative values. You can use v5 until that is fixed:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/5.0.14/highcharts.js"></script>
```

**Edit:** Fixed in v6.0.1 (https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/7228).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `yAxis` options as workaround - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/5xwpqms2/)